# Universal app in windows

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have just started to develop in universal app. I have developed app in Windows  8 store apps and also developing Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 (SilverLight) Apps. I have few questions related to universal app in Windows . I have posted them below. Most of cases are related Single UI which is created in App. Share folder.

**1.** Is there any control in universal app like **Pivot** or **panorama** as like windows phone 8 and windows phone 8.1 (silverlight) have ?

**2.** which is best to design for **data binding Listview or Listbox**?

**3.** In c# we can write like

```
#if WINDOWS_APP
    welcometb.Text = "Welcome to Windows App";
#endif
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    welcometb.Text = "Welcome to Windows Phone App";
#endif
```

to get which app is there, for XAMl  how can we determine that it is windows app and it is windows Phone app

**4.** For **web** there is word like **responsive UI**. to create there is media query to write **css**.
I know css is same as we can create **resource with**  for xaml . I can get resolution form c# and I can create different UI for different resolution and I can visible collapsed according to resolution but **is there any single way which automatically adjust according to design**.? ( this question is related to data binding controls specially...)

**5.** I am new in **MVVM**. I have developed Windows phone 8 and WP8.1 app in normal way. But not with MVVM. I have search a lot but did not get any example which can make better understand of MVVM. I know what is MVVM. It is similarly of  MVC of Asp.net.

**MVVM** is

**Model** : Which describe data

**View-Model** : In simple word a bridge between Model and View.

**View** : A simple xaml page or user interface.

Which way is better or best to do code in Windows Phone 8 MVVM or Normal way?

Ref : [Separate UI and app logic using the Model-View-ViewModel pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj721615%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

**6.** I have a transparent Image as Icon but still it display white background check below images

I - > Package.appxmanifest

[image: Package.appxmanifest]

II - > Display in start menu .

[image: Display in start menu]

Comment: You need to post each question separately.

Comment: Yes, please post these questions individually. I can answer most of them, but we need to keep the answers separate so they are helpful to people in future.

Comment: Hi I have posted them sepatately plz check : 

1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631163/universal-app-design-how-to-use-these-controls-pivot-or-panorama-listview-or

2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631179/how-can-i-design-responsive-ui-in-universal-windows-app

3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631202/universal-app-in-windows-mvvm

4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631220/universal-app-in-windows-in-windows-rt-app-not-displayed-transparent-tile