# Universal App design : how to use these controls Pivot or panorama ,Listview or Listbox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have just started to develop in universal app. I have developed app in Windows 8 store apps and also developing Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 (SilverLight) Apps. Question is related to universal app in Windows and Single UI which is created in App. Share folder.

**1.** Is there any control in universal app like **Pivot** or **panorama** as like windows phone 8 and windows phone 8.1 (silverlight) have ?

**2.** which is best to design for **data binding Listview or Listbox**?

**3.** In c# we can write like

```
#if WINDOWS_APP
    welcometb.Text = "Welcome to Windows App";
#endif
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    welcometb.Text = "Welcome to Windows Phone App";
#endif
```

to get which app is there, for XAMl  how can we determine that it is windows app and it is windows Phone app

Comment: These three questions are completely unrelated. Please post them as discrete questions so they can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

1) The equivalent is a hub app.

In the Windows Store project the layout is like a pivot with all the pages open at once. If you think about the screen size/shape/orientation of a Windows tablet compared to a Windows Phone the pivot/panorama layouts don't make sense.

In the phone project the layout is the same as a pivot app more or less.

I can only answer one question per post, so I can't include the answers to 2 & 3.