# Universal app in windows : In Windows RT app not displayed transparent tile

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, live-tile

I have just started to develop in universal app. I have developed app in Windows 8 store apps and also developing Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 (SilverLight) Apps. Question is related to universal app in Windows and Single UI which is created in App. Share folder.

**1.** I have a transparent Image as Icon but still it display white background check below images

I - > Package.appxmanifest

[image: Package.appxmanifest]

II - > Display in start menu .

[image: Display in start menu]

Answer (score 1):

You can't have transparent tiles in Windows Store apps.